# Python Pandas: Loop through dates and add them as new rows to the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a basic dataframe that is read into pandas, with a few rows of existing data that don't matter much.

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

I need to be able to come up with a method that will allow me to loop through between two dates and add these as new rows. These dates are on a cycle, 21 days out of 28 day cycle. So if the start date was 4/1/13 and my end date was 6/1/19, I want to be able to add a row for each date, 21 days on and off for a week.

Desired output:

```
A, Date
x, 4/1/13
x, 4/2/13
x, 4/3/13
x, 4/4/13
x, 4/5/13
... cont'd
x, 4/21/13
y, 4/29/13
y, 4/30/13
... cont'd
```

You can see that between x and y there was a new cycle.

I think I am supposed to use Datetime for this but please correct me if I am wrong. I am not sure where to start.

**EDIT**
I started with this:

```
import datetime

# The size of each step in days
day_delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

start_date = datetime.date(2013, 4, 1)
end_date = start_date + 21*day_delta

for i in range((end_date - start_date).days):
    print(start_date + i*day_delta)
```

And got this:

```
2013-04-01
2013-04-02
2013-04-03
2013-04-04
2013-04-05
2013-04-06
2013-04-07
2013-04-08
2013-04-09
2013-04-10
2013-04-11
2013-04-12
2013-04-13
2013-04-14
2013-04-15
2013-04-16
2013-04-17
2013-04-18
2013-04-19
2013-04-20
2013-04-21
```

But I am not sure how to implement the cycle in here.

TYIA!

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Stack Overflow is not a design or tutorial resource.  "I don't know how to write my program" is an issue for a local tutor, or exercises in problem analysis; it is not a specific programming problem.

Comment: You need to compare consecutive dates and find the ones with the expected gap.  Comparing adjacent items is a well-covered data frame topic.

Comment: It's not a matter of how advanced you are: it's whether your question adds to the answers in the Stack Overflow archives.  We specifically work to *not* duplicate questions that are readily covered in other places, such as tutorials and previous SO questions.  You will see this principle covered throughout the intro tour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question, I spent almost half an hour on this.
Yes, you will need the `datetime` module for this.

```
base = datetime.datetime.today()
date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(100)]
```

I made a list of dates as you did. This is a list of `datetime.timedelta` objects. I recommend you convert all your dates into this format to make calculations easier. We set a base date (the first day) to compare with the rest later on in a loop.

```
date_list_filtered = []
for each in enumerate(date_list):
  date_list_filtered.append(each[1].strftime('%d/%m/%y'))
```

`strftime()` changes the `datetime.datetime` object into a readable date, my own preference is using the dd/mm/yy format. You can look up different formats online.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Raw':date_list,'Date':date_list_filtered})
```

[image: The Dataframe:]

Here I made a loop to count the difference in days between each date in the loop and the base date, changing the base date every time it hits -21.
Edit: Oops I did 21 days instead of 28, but I'm sure you can tweak it

```
base = df['Raw'][0]

unique_list = []

no21 = 0
for date in df['Raw'].values:
  try:
    res = (date-base).days
  except:
    res = (date-base).astype('timedelta64[D]')/np.timedelta64(1, 'D')

  if res==-21.0:
    base = date
    #print(res)
    unique_list.append(string.ascii_letters[no21])
    no21+=1
  else:
    unique_list.append(string.ascii_letters[no21])
```

I used the `string` library to get the unique letters I wanted.
Lastly, put it in the data frame.

```
df['Unique'] = unique_list
```

[image: Result:]

Thanks for asking this question, it was really fun.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this question! I will give this try. I’m glad there are supportive people on SO :)

Answer (score 0):

You can floor divide the difference in days from the start date by 28 to get the number of cycles.

```
date_start = datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 1)
date1 = datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 26)
```

And to check the difference

```
diff_days = (date1-date_start).days
diff_days
55

cycle = (date1-date_start).days//28
cycle
1
```

Then you can sum over the dates within the same cycle.

Comment: Thank you SO much for taking the time to answer my question. I will give this a try!